# Vaadin 10 is not using templates in Spring-Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, polymer, vaadin10

I am trying to use templates with Vaadin 10 in a Spring-Boot application.

The problem is, that the template is not used when the page is displayed.
No components of the template are appearing on the page.

My template `PersonForm.html` is stored in `src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/frontend/src`.

The class which is trying to bind them is:

```
@Route
@Tag("person-form")
@HtmlImport("frontend://src/PersonForm.html")
public class PersonView extends VerticalLayout implements HasUrlParameter<String> {  

    public PersonView() {}

    @Override
    public void setParameter(BeforeEvent event, String parameter) {}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's right to put the templates in `src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/frontend`. For Spring-Boot at least this is the default folder.

The Problem is, that your class which is using the template, must extend `PolymerTemplate<TemplateModel>`.

Instead of `TemplateModel` you can use your own model.

This will work:

```
@Tag("person-form")
@HtmlImport("frontend://src/PersonForm.html")
public class PersonView extends PolymerTemplate<TemplateModel> implements HasUrlParameter<String> {
```

[Documentation](https://vaadin.com/docs/v10/flow/polymer-templates/tutorial-template-bindings.html).